# Dynamic values for @Input in Directive from Component (Angular 4, 5, 6)

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Input defined in Directive:

`@Input items: any[];`

Data defined in Component:

`data: string[] = ['Item 1', Item 2', 'Item 3'];`

Directive used in component template:

`<input type="text" myDirective [items]="data">`

**How can we update values of `items` in Directive whenever `data` array is changed in Component?**

For example, if the `data` in Component updated to:

`data: string[] = ['Item 1', Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4'];`

The `'Item 4'` must be accessible inside Directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getter setter` by typescript like this -

```
private items: any;

@Input() set items(value: any) {

   this._categoryId = value;
   this.doSomething(this._categoryId);

}

get items(): any {

    return this._categoryId;

}
```

- Second Method -

or you could simply use `ngOnChanges` for any changes in the digest cycle like this -

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      /// your changes in the binding
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pushing data into the array will not be detected by the directive. You need the change the whole reference of the `data` to a newer array.

Then you can listen to the `OnChanges` life cycle event on the directive and check the data's value

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   /// changes.data
}
```